# Generate table with proportions of success vs failure

Tags: r, r-factor

I want to calculate the error rate by interval where `0` is good and `1` is bad. If I have a sample of 100 observation as levels divided in intervals as follows:

```
X <- 10; q<-sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=X)
l <- sample(c(1:100),replace=T,size=10)

bornes<-seq(min(l),max(l),5)
v <- cut(l,breaks=bornes,include.lowest=T)
table(v)
```

How can I get a table or function that calculates the default rate by each interval, the number of bad observations divided by the total number of observations?

```
tx_erreur<-function(x){
    t<-table(x,q)
    return(sum(t[,2])/sum(t))
}
```

I already tried this code above and tapply.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
tapply(q,# the variable to be summarized
       v,# the variable that defines the bins
       function(x) # the function to calculate the summary statistics within each bin
           sum(x)/length(x))
```